# iBeacon Monitoring While Device is Locked iOS 8.1

Tags: ios8, core-location, ibeacon

I've been playing around with this for days now and the only conclusion I can come to is that CoreLocation is pretty buggy for this setup in iOS 8.1.

I had code that was correctly monitoring for a region (using UUID only, no major/minor) and the delegate methods `didEnterRegion` and `didExitRegion` were being called correctly, while the device was locked and the app had been terminated, which is what I want. These even worked after a reboot without issue.

I modified the code to pull some more UUIDs from a server and to start monitoring for those regions (only two more). They're working, but only while the device is awake and unlocked, the moment the screen is powered off then I get no hits on the delegate methods at all. The first UUID I used continued to work while these didn't, so I removed the app from the device to stop it from counting (I'm not calling `stopMonitoring` anywhere right now).... the two new regions still don't work when locked though.

Every version of iOS I've tried has exhibited different behaviour with beacons, and this is the most annoying one yet because when it was working it was being very responsive—powering up a beacon with the beacon with the first UUID would trigger delegate calls within a couple of seconds—but now it's just refusing to work.

Does anyone have any ideas around what's going on internally in CoreLocation and what I might be able to do to make this more reliable? Capabilities etc. are all present and correct as evidenced by the fact that it was working fine with the one region.

Comment: How many total regions are you monitoring for? And are you aware of other apps on the phone that might be monitoring for beacon regions? While the phone is a black box and I can only guess how it works, it seems there is a limit to the number of regions that can be monitored until the phone falls back to a "best effort" monitoring.

Comment: Only two regions total, as far as I can see from the apple docs apps belonging to a particular provider are limited to 20 regions between them, though right now nothing else on there should be monitoring at all.